# postgres join table with condition and limitation

Tags: sql, postgresql, pg-trgm

I need to join 6 tables by item_name,
(The DB of each table is lower than 10k items except 1 table with 30k,table_1 is the samllest with 5k items)

I join tables by same id or name where them both are b-tree indeces,
the join by name based on the pg_trgm similar enough.

```
SELECT * FROM 'TABLE_1' ta,
JOIN 'TABLE_2' tb ON tb.item_code = ta.item_code or tb.item_name % ta.item_name,
.
.
.
JOIN 'TABLE_6' tf ON tf.item_code = tf.item_name or tf.item_name 5 ta.item_name
```

In this example i'm using "%" for similar enogth, if instead similar enough i will use "=" operator it will take 36 ms only.

i have many misunderstandings with this example.my mention is to get the 1 result pet item if item codes are equal or 3-4 results if similar enogh (dont know how to limit it in my exapmle)

1. why is it so slow ? (50% of the result the item_code comparison return true so it shuldnt use similar enogth for all the data... in other words if the left condition of or statment are true it doesnt check the right condition)
2. how can i limit the result cames from similar enogth ?
   lets say

```
tableA : item_name = 'laptop'
tableB : item_name = 'laptop a"
tableB : item_name = 'laptop b"
tableB : item_name = 'laptop c"
```

| id | item_name_a | item_name_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | laptop | laptop a |
| 1 | laptop | laptop b |
| 1 | laptop | laptop c |

it will join them all and if i want to limit it to 2 result, how can i do it?

Comment: The `%` operator means modulo (remainder after integer division), and works on numbers.  Do you mean to use a [pattern-matching operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) instead?

Comment: Nope. i mention that im using pg_trgm that using % for similar enogh function. here it doesnt works as modulo.

Comment: Oh, right. Missed that.

Comment: use regular expression they are usually faster than similar to

Comment: @nbk , i cant see how to mimic similarity algorithm with regex and make it better. i compare thousands of differnet strings

Comment: @Bennyh961 see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions-in-postgresql

Comment: If each join to tables 2 through 6 produce 3 rows each, that would a total of 3^5 = 243 rows.  It seems unlikely that this is what you want.  I think a UNION between 5 pairwise joins would be more suitable.

Comment: "why is it so slow".  You haven't told us how slow it is.  Looking into that type of question should always start with an EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) of the query.

Comment: @jjanes mostly it kill my CPU so i cant say how much .
and i will glad to explain more but i dont understand the format u suggested EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) of the query.

Comment: It depends on your client.  For `psql`, you just put the text 'EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)' at the start of the command-line, then finish with the text of the query.  Other clients might have other ways to do it, but this method should still work for them too.  If the query never finishes, then you could still EXPLAIN it without the ANALYZE to get at least some information.

Answer (score 1):

**Not an answer**

It's some questions to your question: Based on your query, assume there're only two tables `t1` and `t2`:

Table `t1`:

```
id|nm|
--+--+
 1|a |
 2|b |
 3|c |
```

Table `t2`:

```
id|nm|
--+--+
 1|a |
11|ab|
12|ac|
 2|b |
21|bb|
22|bc|
 3|c |
31|cb|
32|cc|
 4|d |
41|db|
42|dd|
```

By apply your query logic:

```sql
select t1.id  as t1_id,
       t2.id  as t2_id,
       t1.nm  as t1_nm,
       t2.nm  as t2_nm
  from t1
  join t2
    on t1.id = t2.id
    or t2.nm like t1.nm || '%';
```

We get:

```
t1_id|t2_id|t1_nm|t2_nm|
-----+-----+-----+-----+
    1|    1|a    |a    |
    1|   11|a    |ab   |
    1|   12|a    |ac   |
    2|    2|b    |b    |
    2|   21|b    |bb   |
    2|   22|b    |bc   |
    3|    3|c    |c    |
    3|   31|c    |cb   |
    3|   32|c    |cc   |
```

You can see that even `t1.id`=`t2.id`, it doesn't stop the comparison `t2.nm like t1.nm || '%'`. Thus, the `inner join` in the query is actually a nested loop as:

```
for each row r1 in t1
   for each row r2 in t2
      compare r1 and r2
      if match then return (r1, r2)
               else next
```

Therefore, the `join` is like `cross join` (Cartesian product of rows from the tables in the join. ie. 5k x 10k = 50m) during execution because it tries to find every match between `t1.nm` and `t2.nm` regardless if `t1.id=t2.id` or not.

If the business rule is: when `t1.id=t2.id`, then remove the row from both tables and do the comparison for the rest. You may want to modify your query into a few steps:

Step 1. Do `item_code` join only and get `matched_items`

Step 2. Derive `unmatched_items_t[1..6]` by subtract `matched_items` from `table_[1..6]`

Step 3. Do string match comparison between `unmatched_items_t1` and `unmatched_items_t[2..6]`: (t1 vs t2), (t1 vs t3), (t1 vs t4), (t1 vs t5), (t1 vs t6)

Step 4. Aggregate the 5 comparison results to `t1.item_code` level.

**UPDATE: Could be an answer**

Assume there are three tables `t1`, `t2`, `t3` as below:

```sql
create table t1 (cd int primary key, nm varchar);
create table t2 (cd int primary key, nm varchar);
create table t3 (cd int primary key, nm varchar);

insert into t1
values
(1, 'a'),
(2, 'b'),
(3, 'c'),
(4, 'd'),
(5, 'e');

insert into t2
values
( 2, 'b'),
(21, 'a 2'),
(22, 'd 2'),
(23, 'x');

insert into t3
values
( 3, 'c'),
(31, 'a 3'),
(32, 'e 3'),
(33, 'y');
```

We want to do `code` match and then `name` match:

- `cte_universe`: this is the universe of item's code and name from t1's perspective
- `cte_t1_cd_matched`: code-matched data by comparing t1, t2, t3
- `cte_t1_cd_unmatched`: code not matched in t1 from the above
- `cte_[t2|t3]_cd_unmatched`: code not matched in t2, t3
- `cte_nm_matched_flat`: name-matched by name by table (src)
- `cte_nm_matched`: aggregate the above to code level
- output code-matched data union all name-matched data

```sql
with cte_item_universe as (
select t1.cd,
       t1.nm,
       case when t2.cd is null then 0 else 1 end is_t2_cd_matched,
       case when t3.cd is null then 0 else 1 end is_t3_cd_matched
  from t1 
  left
  join t2 using (cd)
  left
  join t3 using (cd)),
cte_t1_cd_matched as (
select cd, nm from cte_item_universe where is_t2_cd_matched + is_t3_cd_matched > 0),
cte_t1_cd_unmatched as (
select cd, nm from cte_item_universe where is_t2_cd_matched + is_t3_cd_matched = 0),
cte_t2_cd_unmatched as (
select t.cd, t.nm from t2 t left join cte_t1_cd_matched m using (cd) where m.cd is null),
cte_t3_cd_unmatched as (
select t.cd, t.nm from t3 t left join cte_t1_cd_matched m using (cd) where m.cd is null),
cte_nm_matched_flat as (
select s.cd, t.nm, 't2' as src
  from cte_t1_cd_unmatched s, cte_t2_cd_unmatched t
 where t.nm like s.nm || '%'
union all
select s.cd, t.nm, 't3' as src
  from cte_t1_cd_unmatched s, cte_t3_cd_unmatched t
 where t.nm like s.nm || '%'),
cte_nm_matched as (
select cd, string_agg(nm || ' (' || src || ') ', ',') as nm
  from cte_nm_matched_flat
 group by cd)
select *, 'code' as reason from cte_t1_cd_matched
union all
select *, 'name' as reason from cte_nm_matched;
```

Output:

```
cd|nm                 |reason|
--+-------------------+------+
 2|b                  |code  |
 3|c                  |code  |
 1|a 2 (t2) ,a 3 (t3) |name  |
 4|d 2 (t2)           |name  |
 5|e 3 (t3)           |name  |
```

Comment: Exactly!!! this is my question and accutaly you answered it . i'm still learning the postgres lang and logic and im not sure i fully understand the way u suggest to solve it. Can u describe the new query more please?

Comment: step 1 : ok , join by item_code
step2 : i guess u mean to query ```select * from t1 where t1.item_code is not in 'step1 query result'  (or can u suggest better ?)
step 3: on step 2 i do join to other tables on t1.name % t2.name....t1.name%t6.name?
step4 : not understand how to .

anyway step 1-3 i already tried before and it still very kill my CPU without getting results

Comment: @Bennyh961 added an updated query for your reference.